# How do I fix the "pip not recognized error" in VS code

Tags: python-requests

So I am new to learning python and I am following a project guide in VS code. It has me type in the terminal "pip get requests bs4" to continue with the guide. But whenever I type it in, I get this error:

---

"*pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pip get requests bs4
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException*"
  ```

---

I have literally tried everything, researched everywhere and nothing. I tried repairing python, I tried adding the "path" to my environment variables. Nothing worked. Looking for some help as this is kind of putting a halt on my python learning.